# Gremlin - Update or insert multiple vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I'm trying the following gremlin query to replace existing vertices if they exist but line `V(__.select('id')).drop()` keeps failing because `__.select('id')` does not return the id on that line.

```
vertices = [
    {"id":1, "label": "person", "first_name":"bob","age":25,"height": 177},
    {"id":2, "label": "person", "first_name":"joe","surname":"bloggs", "age": 32}
]

graph_traversal.inject(vertices).unfold().as_('entity'). \
   V(__.select('id')).drop(). \
   addV(__.select('label')).property(T.id, __.select('id')).as_('vertex'). \
   sideEffect(__.select('entity').unfold().as_('kv').select('vertex'). \
       property(
           __.select('kv').by(Column.keys),
           __.select('kv').by(Column.values)
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to approach it, but it requires that you do a bit of front end processing to your `List` of `Map` data to extract the "id" values so that they can be passed to `g.V()` directly.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> data = [
......1>     ["id":1, "label": "person", "first_name":"bob","age":25,"height": 177],
......2>     ["id":2, "label": "person", "first_name":"joe","surname":"bloggs", "age": 32]
......3> ]
==>[id:1,label:person,first_name:bob,age:25,height:177]
==>[id:2,label:person,first_name:joe,surname:bloggs,age:32]
gremlin> g.V(data.collect{it.id}).
......1>   sideEffect(drop()).
......2>   fold().
......3>   constant(data).
......4>   unfold().as('properties').
......5>   addV(select('label')).property(T.id, select('id')).as('vertex').
......6>   sideEffect(select('properties').
......7>              unfold().as('kv').
......8>              where(select(keys).is(without('id','label'))).
......9>              select('vertex').
.....10>              property(select('kv').by(keys), select('kv').by(values)))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V(1,2).elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,first_name:bob,age:25,height:177]
==>[id:2,label:person,surname:bloggs,first_name:joe,age:32]
```

Of particular note here is the use of `fold()` to reduce the stream of dropped vertex traversers to a single traverser (i.e. a `List` of those vertices) which then let's us replace that with a single instance of "data" to iterate over in the common fashion for using a `Map` to create a `Vertex`. Note that I added a `where()` to ignore the "id" and "label" keys since I figured you didn't want those values duplicated in as vertex properties.